# Как отключить кнопку отправки формы, пока не правильно заполнено поле

Tags: javascript, inputmask

Использую маску для ввода телефона, плагин `jquery.maskedinput`

```
<input type="text" name="utel" id="utel" class="form-control" placeholder="Ваш телефон" required />
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-second btn-submit btn-block" disabled="disabled">Отправить</button>
```

а вот js

```
$("#utel").mask("+7 (999) 999 - 9999",{
    autoclear: false,
    completed: function(){ button.removeAttribute('disabled'); }
});
```

Надо чтобы после правильного заполнения поля телефон (11 цифр), с баттона убирался атрибут `disabled`. Но не убирается. Причем, если в `completed: function(){ ... }` подставить например `alert('Заполнено верно')`, то при введении всех 11 цифр, вылезает алерт.
То бишь, проблема именно в  `button.removeAttribute('disabled');`, все остальное верно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой вариант на jquery `$('.btn-submit').prop('disabled', false);`